# JQuery ¿cómo procesar las filas de una tabla que cumplan una condición?

Tags: jquery

Tengo el siguiente código. El mismo procesa TODAS las filas de una tabla.

```js
var d_cantidadDevArray = [];
$("#tablaDetalleVentas tbody tr").each(function() {
 d_cantidadDevArray.push($(this).find("#tdCantDevuelta").val());
});
```

La pregunta es:

¿Cómo proceso SOLAMENTE las filas que sean distintas de cero en la columna "Cantidad a devolver"? es un input #tdCantDevuelta, que está dentro de una celda.

Todos los aportes son bienvenidos.

ejemplo de la tabla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No deberías tener IDs repetidos en tu página, puede crear problemas con el código más adelante

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con la función each de jquery en su segundo parámetro obtienes el elemento tr que estarás iterando, apartir de ahi puedes buscar elementos que estén dentro del Tr.

```
var d_cantidadDevArray = [];
$("#tabla tbody tr").each(function(k, tr) {
  var cantidad = parseInt($('.cantidad', tr).val());
  if(cantidad !== 0){
     d_cantidadDevArray.push(cantidad);
  }
});
```

[El ejemplo esta aqui](https://plnkr.co/edit/zgArIsBoIrP2qzMoF6oY?p=preview)

Comment: Funciona perfecto, no sabía que se podía hacer así.  Muchas gracias Omar! Saludos.

Comment: @Gustavo si la respuesta te funciona, puedes elegirla como la solución a esta pregunta (para indicar que se solucionó). La forma indicada de hacerlo es marcando la respuesta con la paloma verde que aparece debajo de las flechas para votar.

Comment: Ok, gracias @Chofoteddy.

Answer (score 0):

Aquí te voy a dejar una alternativa a la [solución propuesta por Omar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/15708/250). Idealmente se usaría con clases en lugar de con id's porque tener id's repetidos hace que el código no sea válido y puede crear problemas a la hora de seleccionar elementos con JavaScript/jQuery.

Esta solución funciona un poco diferente porque en lugar de atravesar todas las filas buscando la que tenga el `input` con valor diferente de 0, lo que se hace es buscar todos los `input` con valor diferente a cero y entonces seleccionar la fila que la contiene:

```
$('#tablaDetalleVentas tbody tr #tdCantDevuelta')    // idealmente esto sería una clase
    .filter(function(){ return this.value != 0; })   // seleccionamos los valores != 0
    .each(function() {                               // para cada uno de ellos
        var fila = $(this).closest("tr");            // seleccionamos la fila
        // operaciones con la fila
    });
```

El código de arriba funciona incluso cuando se cambia el valor de los `input`. Pero si el valor de los `input` fuera constante (no se cambiara porque son de sólo lectura o están deshabilitados), entonces se podría simplificar más usando el [selector de atributo "no igual" (`!=`)](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector/):

```
$('#tablaDetalleVentas tbody tr #tdCantDevuelta[value!="0"]').each(function() { 
    var fila = $(this).closest("tr");
    // operaciones con la fila
});
```

Comment: Muy buen aporte! Es verdad con los id#, cambié por clases, no me di cuenta que es una tabla dinámica...y se pueden generar errores. El código también lo probé y funciona perfecto. Gracias!